# Select rows missing from link table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables.  One is a table of services.  Each service can have some options, which are in the options table.  The third table is a list of contacts linked to each option.

So, the tables look like this:

**services**

```
serviceID
   100
   101
```

**options**

```
optionID    serviceID    price
    1         100        10.5
    2         100        100
    3         101        25.25
    4         101        67.90
```

**contactOptions**

```
contactID     optionID     serviceID     priceOverride
    10            1           100              NULL
    10            2           100              NULL
    10            3           101              30
    10            4           101              100
    11            1           100              12
    11            3           101              NULL
    12            2           100              55
    12            3           101              NULL
    12            4           101              NULL
    13            1           100              NULL
    13            2           100              66
    13            4           101              NULL
```

As you can see contactID 10 has all 4 options linked to him.  11 has only 2 linked to her, and 12 and 13 both only have 3.

I am trying to find a way to get the contactIDs that don't have all 4 options, and which ones they are missing.

I have tried (SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca937/7):

```
SELECT *
FROM contactOptions
LEFT JOIN options
  ON options.optionID = contactOptions.optionID
  AND options.serviceID = contactOptions.serviceID
```

but this just returns me all 12 rows, I want the opposite, the rows that *don't exist*.

How can I return the contacts that don't have all 4 options, and the options they don't have?

The returned rows should be:

```
contactID    optionID    serviceID
  11           2            100
  11           4            101
  12           1            100
  13           3            101
```

I ultimately want to find out which services (and which of its options) don't have contacts linked to them.

**EDIT**: I've been getting closer, here is what I have now

```
SELECT contactID,
  contactOptions.serviceID,contactOptions.optionID AS x,
  options.optionID AS y
FROM contactOptions
JOIN options
  ON options.serviceID = contactOptions.serviceID
HAVING x != y
```

Here is my current SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca937/35

This returns:

```
CONTACTID    SERVICEID    X    Y
  10           100        1    2
  10           100        2    1
  10           101        3    4
  10           101        4    3
  11           100        1    2
  11           101        3    4
  12           100        2    1
  12           101        3    4
  12           101        4    3
  13           100        1    2
  13           100        2    1
  13           101        4    3
```

This contains the rows I want, but it also contains rows I don't.  From this result I basically need to remove all rows where a contact has the same values for X and Y, then the rows remaining are correct.

**EDIT 2**: I'm even closer now (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca937/53):

```
SELECT contactID,
  contactOptions.serviceID,contactOptions.optionID AS x,
  options.optionID AS y
FROM contactOptions
JOIN options
  ON options.serviceID = contactOptions.serviceID
GROUP BY contactID,serviceID
HAVING x != y
```

This gives me:

```
CONTACTID    SERVICEID    X    Y
  12            100       2    1
  13            101       4    3
```

Now I have 2 of the rows I want.  I just need to figure out how to get the rows for 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT contacts_options_full.contactID, contacts_options_full.optionID, options.serviceID
FROM
(
  SELECT contactID, optionID
  FROM (SELECT optionID FROM options) o
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT contactID FROM contactOptions) co
) contacts_options_full
LEFT JOIN contactOptions ON contacts_options_full.contactID = contactOptions.contactID
AND contactOptions.optionID = contacts_options_full.optionID
JOIN options ON contacts_options_full.optionID = options.optionID
WHERE contactOptions.serviceID IS NULL
ORDER BY contacts_options_full.contactID, contacts_options_full.optionID
```

on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca937/78)

Comment: Woah!  That works! Thanks :-)  It's got a lot of JOINs and subqueries, but it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,COUNT(contactID)as cc
FROM contactOptions
GROUP BY contactID
HAVING cc < 4
```

Of course to calc all options just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM options
```

### Edit for comments:

After do you have all your contactID with previous query you can run this query for each of your contactID:

```
SELECT optionID FROM options WHERE optionID NOT IN (SELECT optionID FROM contactOptions WHERE contactID = 11)
```

Comment: I don't know the total number of services beforehand.

Comment: I believe you can calculate it with a previous query someway. Otherwise you can't solve this

Comment: This can show me the contacts that are missing options, but can I figure out what those options are (without having to use PHP)?

Comment: I have added the last query... But I doubt it can be done within a single query. Take care to +1 if this helped you

Comment: Your last query actually helped.  A lot.  Check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca937/81 BAM!  Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Not bad. It's the first time i see NOT IN used like that :S (not in a WHERE clause). Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: `IN` (or `NOT IN`) is just a [comparison function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html).  It returns `0` or `1`, and therefore can be used in an `ON` clause :-P

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this a bit more, and I came up with my own answer.

```
SELECT serviceContact.contactID, options.optionID,
serviceContact.serviceID

FROM options
JOIN(
  SELECT DISTINCT contactID, services.serviceID, GROUP_CONCAT(optionID) as options
  FROM contactOptions
  JOIN services ON services.serviceID = contactOptions.serviceID
  GROUP BY contactID, services.serviceID
) serviceContact ON serviceContact.serviceID = options.serviceID

WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(optionID,serviceContact.options)
```

There trick here is the `GROUP_CONCAT` mixed with the `NOT FIND_IN_SET`.  This lets me get the options *not* in the link table.

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca937/87

Comment: @yes123: That seemed to work ok on SQL Fiddle, but when I tried that on my real database (with a slightly different structure), it didn't return the right rows.  In my system, it's ok for a contact to have 0 options, that query was JOINing the contacts with each service, and returning me too may rows.